# apt install in Dockefile

Tags: docker, openssl, dockerfile, debian, apt

I have a docker file with image which contain Debian.
because of vulnerabilities I tried to change version of open ssl in dockerfile.
the current used version 1.1.0j-1~deb9u1  im tried to install different version using:

```
RUN apt-get install openssl=1.1.0l-1~deb9u1
```

but I keep getting -

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Version '1.1.0l-1~deb9u1' for 'openssl' was not found
```

what should I do to enable installation of different stable version.

Comment: Provide the minimal reproducible example. It's not clear which debian you are using, what are other libraries that might be installed, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your selection of the package version and based on the information from [the debian package repository](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/openssl), I assume that your debian version is `stretch`. The following `dockerfile` worked for me:

```
FROM debian:stretch
  
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openssl=1.1.0l-1~deb9u1
```

After `docker build -t debian-openssl .`the installed openssl version can be verified like this:

```
$ docker run -t debian-openssl openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.0l  10 Sep 2019
```